# JOLT transform based on match condition

Tags: json, jolt

I am trying to transform `JSON` to `JSON` using `JOLT` based on match condition.

If 'type': 'true', do the processing.

`JSON` input:

```
{
     "features": [
        {
           "type": "true",
           "properties": {
           "class_lvl": "U",
           "image_url": [
              "http://www.google.com/149231_294002.jpg",
              "https://www.google.com/149231_294002.jpg"
           ],
           "review_date": "2019-03-27T15:42:02.523"              
         }
      }
    ]
  }
```

The `JOLT` specs I came up with but it is not generating out put the way I want:

```
 [
      {
          "operation": "shift",
          "spec": {
          "features": {
            "*": {
              "properties": {            
               //go up one level and check if type = true then copy image URL
                "@(1,type)": {              
                  "true": {
                    "image_url": "Parent[&3].child.grandchild"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
   ]
```

Comment: In `JSON` you are trying to get `RemarkComposite` key is duplicated which is considered as a bug. Most `JSON` deserialisers skip one during deserialisation.

Answer (score 0):

This Spec works:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "features": {
        "*": {
          //"type": "Parent[#].child.grandchild.type",
          "properties": {
            //go up one level and check if type = true then copy image URL
            "@(1,type)": {
              "true": {
                "@2": "Parent[#].child.grandchild"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ]
```